# Was Pyotr Stepanovich in "Demons" really connected to the international?

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, demons

In the noval *Demons* (by Dostoyevsky), there was a character, named Pyotr Stepanovich Verkhovensky, who claimed that he was connected to the international.

Did Dostoyevsky mention anywhere in the book that he really was?

Comment: I haven't read the book, so apologies if this is clarified in it, but: that is a rather odd use of "international", as a noun. What does it mean? Is "the international" some group within the book?

Comment: The [International Working Men Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Workingmen%27s_Association) was an organization of a certain historical importance.